# Help me decode Haro serial number to find out info on it

Tags: identify-this-bike, serial-number

I am needing assistance in finding the information on my Haro bike the serial number is H8710870

[image: under tube]

Answer (score 4):

You can find some useful info over here [Decoder Info](https://shop.re-rides.com/blogs/news/how-to-read-haro-serial-numbers-for-mid-school-and-new-school-bmx-bikes)

Looking at your serial number tells me it's October 1987.

More info can be found over the BMX museum, the link can be found from the link posted above or here [BMX Museum Haro](https://bmxmuseum.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=206889)